# How to get a process variable value from a map file address in Linux

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux

For example, if I have a map file like this,
　`0x00001000 _hoge`
how do I get the value of the variable "hoge" from this address(0x00001000) in a process running in Linux?

In the case of a normal (without OS) embedded program, it is processed only by the physical address, so I think that the following code is fine.
　`value = (*(volatile unsigned int*)0x00001000)`

On the other hand, process running in Linux use virtual addresses, so I don't think this method works.

[add more details]

This is a story in an environment where linux is embedded in a microcomputer.
I use the programming language c(gcc).
The purpose is to create a function that sends the address described in the mapfile to the microcomputer from the outside and sends back the value of the corresponding variable.

Comment: You seems confused. Read [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [ptrace(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html), [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/), [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), [shm_overview(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) and a good [operating system textbook](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

Comment: You could also study the source code of the [kernel](http://kernel.org/), and look inside [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)... both are [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html). Play also with [pmap(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html) and [readelf(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html)

Comment: i'm curious for more context as to why you want to read another process's private memory.